# This Code Not Working. Why?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

puts.php (JSON)

```
 {
    "image":[
       {
          "name":'<div id="yes">Hi!</div>'
       }
    ]
 }
```

process.php

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Process</TITLE>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function loadPage() {

                $(document).ready(function () {

                    $.getJSON('puts.php', function (JSON) {
                        $('#result').empty();

                        $.each(JSON.image, function (i, img) {
                            $('#result').append(img.name)
                        });
                    });
                });
            }

            function loadEfect() {

                $(document).ready(function () {

                    $('#yes').fadeOut();
                    $('#yes').fadeIn();
                });
            }

            function start() {

                loadPage();
                loadEfect();
            }
        </script>
    </HEAD>

    <BODY onLoad="start()">
        <div id="result"></div>
    </BODY>

</HTML>
```

`process.php` code in the `loadEfect()` function does not work. (`fadeIn`, `fadeOut` not working) The page is loaded `loadPage()` function to work, but `loadEfect()` function does not work. Why is this? Where can I made ​​a mistake? Please help.

Comment: try debugging it with firebug or similar to get a better error message. if you load a script with syntax errors using javascript, you won't see the error message generated

Comment: I think part of it is having two `$(document).ready()` functions...

Comment: I believe, all strings in JSON have to be double-quoted... **check the error-console**

Comment: @AndrewPeacock: That doesn't matter.  They are ran in the order they are added.

Comment: @Rocket Oh, I was unaware of that. Thanks!

Comment: _"This Code Not Working. Why?"_ isn't the best title you know...

Comment: Why are you using `onload` and `$(document).ready` at the same time?

Comment: @gdoron So good it earned an instant -1 from me... (the rest of the post is no better)

Comment: @pst. Maybe, "Not working" title equals to -10 to me, so I didn't even bother reading it... thanks for verifying to for me. I owe you one! `:)`

Answer (score 3):

`loadEfect` isn't working because there's no element with the ID `yes`.

Also, don't use both `onload` and `$(document).ready(`.  Only use one method.

```
function loadPage() {
    $.getJSON('puts.php', function (JSON) {
        $('#result').empty();
        $.each(JSON.image, function (i, img) {
            $('#result').append(img.name)
        });
    });
}

function loadEfect() {
    $('#yes').fadeOut();
    $('#yes').fadeIn();
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    loadPage();
    loadEfect();
}
```

Then remove `onLoad="start()"` from your `<body>` tag.

Comment: I did say, but the code did not give any response? Can you show me how exactly should I write?

Comment: @WiseColt: what are you having trouble with?  Just replace your `<script>` tag's contents with the code above and replace `<BODY onLoad="start()">` with just `<BODY>`.

Comment: I did say, but loadEfect () function does not work again. fadeOut() and fadeIn() not working..

Comment: $ ('# yes'). fadeIn () instead of $ ('# result'). fadeIn() is working. ?  But $ ('# yes'). FadeIn () does not work.

Comment: @WiseColt: Do you have an element called `yes`?  What's working and, what isn't?  You said `fadeIn` works, and then you said `fadeIn` does not work.

Answer (score 2):

Its not working because `onload` happens after `onready`. try something like this:

```
$(function(){
    $.getJSON('puts.php' function(json){
        $.each(json.image, function(i, img){
            $('#result').append(img.name)
        };
    });

    $('#yes').fadeOut();
    $('#yes').fadeIn(); 
});
```

Comment: The order of `onload` and `onready` doesn't make a difference here.

Comment: @Rocket: becuase hes kicking off actually attaching the effect stuff to the `onready` event after that event has already happend.

Comment: @prodigitalson: That doesn't actually matter.  In jQuery if you attach `$(document).ready(` after it's ready, it'll still get fired. :-)

Comment: İ don't anderstand.  
How should you organize code process.php?

Answer (score 1):

Only use double-quoted stings in your JSON:

```
{
    "image": [
        {
            "name": "<div id='yes'>Hi!</div>"
        }
    ]
}
```

Single-quoted strings are not allowed. See [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/).